# DataReader Exception

Tags: c#, sql, loops, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have a simple database that I am using. It contains two entries for users which is a user with UserID 1 and IsAdmin 0 and another with UserID 3041234567 and IsAdmin of 1. The only fields in the database is a string UserID and a bit IsAdmin. I am reading from the database with the following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Conn);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + t.Text.ToString(), conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{

    while (reader.Read())
         {
                user.UserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
                user.IsAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsAdmin"]);
         }
}

conn.Close();
```

If I enter the number 3041234567 as the UserID everything works perfectly, but If I enter the number 1 I get an exception saying that "The conversion of the nvarchar value '3041234567' overflowed an int column."

If I set a breakpoint and watch the while(reader.read()) loop the loop iterates through fine and sets the user.UserID = 1 and the user.IsAdmin = false. The exception is thrown when the loop begins to iterate a second time. I guess I have a couple of questions:

1. Why is the loop iterating a second time?
2. How is the ID 3041234567 being returned with the sql command `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 1"`
3. What is the int column that is being overflowed?

Comment: If you are only retrieving 1 record with your WHERE statement, remove the loop. Also why is your UserID a string? What is the datatype of the column in your db? Note that a signed int is up to 2147483647. Your UserID for 2nd entry exceeds the acceptable value as an int.

Comment: personally when getting data I always use datatables to being the results back into as it be be much easier to get and place the data. But... in your instance, how many rows are you returning if its looping more than once.  Also, when you put that value in and you set a breakpoint what is the value of t.text? and then what is the value of the entire Select Statment

Comment: First problem: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I would *strongly* advise you to use parameterized SQL.

Comment: Jon has a good point which is what I was going to come to in one of my next comments

Comment: I see. I will change that.

Comment: @ProgrammingDude Why a nvarchar? Any justification?

Comment: @Simon Price The value of the t.text is 1 and the select statement is "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 1"

Comment: @Kai early in app development. Not sure what kind of ID we will be utilizing. They may incorporate something with letters of first and last name or something.

Comment: and is that the value that you are entering in to the textbox?

Comment: Try retrieving your UserID using reader.getString (0) where 0 is the column i assume your UserID is. See if it works.

Comment: @SimonPrice Yes, I am entering a 1 in the textbox.

Comment: Generally good practice to have business level ID's as text fields. But then TREAT THEM AS SUCH. No sense in converting them if they have no meaning and are not an integer.

Comment: @TomTom I'm never converting them. I am always using them as a string. That was why I was wondering where the overflow was coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since

```
  3041234567 > int.MaxValue ( == 2147483647)
```

you've got an *overflow*; if you want some kind of integer value, however, try `long` (which is 64 bit long):

```
  long value = Convert.ToInt64(reader["UserID"]);
```

Something like this:

```
 // Wrap IDisposable into using 
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Conn)) {
   conn.Open();

   // Make sql 
   //  1. Readable 
   //  2. Parametrized
   //  3. Avoid * in select
   String sql = 
     @"select UserID,
              IsAdmin
         from Users
        where UserID = @prm_UserId";

   // Wrap IDisposable into using 
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
     // Explicit data type will be better here (Add Parameter with type)
     // but I don't know it
     cmd.Parameters.AddWidthValue("prm_UserId", t.Text);  

     // Wrap IDisposable into using 
     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
       // You don't want to iterate the whole cursor, but the first record 
       if (reader.Read()) {
         //TODO: Make UserID being "long"
         user.UserID = Convert.ToInt64(reader["UserID"]);
         user.IsAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsAdmin"]);
       } 
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: That would work if I was storing any data as an Int, but I'm not. my UserID in my application and in the database is a string. Thus, the questions as to what int column is being overflowed. However, by changing the while(reader.read()) loop to an if statement did fix my problem.

Comment: If `UserId` is declared in the database as `Char(N)`, `VarChar(N)` or alike, but contains, in fact, digits only you can convert it to long `Convert.ToInt64()`; you have also to change the `User` class - field/method `UserID` must be `long`.

Comment: I don't want them as long. I need it to be a string. Not sure what kind of UserID format we are going to be using. They may decide to include letters from user's first and last names in the UserID.

Comment: If you want items being `String` just convert to `String`: `user.UserID = Convert.ToString(reader["UserID"]);`

Comment: I am still pretty new to this. Does that do anything different than `user.UserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();`

Comment: In *your particular case*, it can well be no difference, however, `ToString()` is often supposed to provide *debug information* when you want representation as a string.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, I've already changed it. I was just curious if there was a difference. Thanks for the help. I just didn't understand what int field was being overflowed and as to why the 3041234567 int was even being returned. Problem was solved though by switching the while loop to an if statement. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, another tip I figured out from your code. If I removed the * from the select statement used the two column values like in your answer the while loop worked fine.

Comment: @ProgrammingDude: do not *fetch* the data you have no need: you want *two* fields only (not *all* of them), so query for these two fields. `*` could be expensive (what if you have *photos* of users in the table), prone to errors (what if you fetch a complex type field)